# .droppable function not working in Inner div

Tags: javascript, jquery

My div structure is some like this,

```
<div class="fromDiv"> 
.......From here I want to drag..........
</div>
<div class="parantDiv">
     <div class="childFirst">
          ..Here Want to drop......
     </div>
     <div class="childSecond">
          ..OrHere Want to drop......
     </div>
</div>
```

I want drag something from `fromDiv` Div...
And want to drop that in `childFirst` Div OR `childSecond Div`....

Please help me out...........

Comment: post your jquery code please

Answer (score 1):

You can use HTML5 Drag and Drop, please check browser support

Simple example

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.fromDiv,.childFirst, .childSecond {
    width: 350px;
    height: 70px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
}
</style>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.innerHTML);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.target.innerHTML = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="fromDiv" draggable="true"
ondragstart="drag(event)"> 
.......From here I want to drag..........
</div>
<div class="parantDiv">
     <div class="childFirst" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          ..Here Want to drop......
     </div>
     <div class="childSecond" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
          ..OrHere Want to drop......
     </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: nice but if we want to drag back to source the dragged data, then this logic is not working.

Comment: @ManavSharma - It depends on your demand, if you want to drag back, you can add drag event in div.childFirst and div.childSecond.

Comment: Ahhh!! Sorry guys...My code was working fine....I just missed a class name...

Thank you